Getting two ros2 clients, on different machines in docker containers, to communicate
I have two machines running in the same network. Both have a docker container, with ros2 installed, running. One of the containers starts a listener and the other container starts a talker Nodes from the Ros2 docs, but the listener isn't getting any of the output from the talker. I have also created a container with a discovery server. The container publishes the port 11811 for the discovery server. The server has been referenced in both nodes with export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER but they still can't communicate.
Setup:
docker-compose.yml from the first machine
services:
  container1:
    image: osrf/ros:foxy-desktop
    container_name: container1
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  discovery_server:
    image: osrf/ros:foxy-desktop
    container_name: discovery_server
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "11811:11811/udp"
      - "11811:11811/tcp"


docker-compose.yml from the second machine
services:
  container2:
    image: osrf/ros:foxy-desktop
    container_name: container1
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

Setup for the discovery server:
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
ros2 daemon stop && ros2 daemon start
fastdds discovery -i 0 -p 11811

Setup for container1:
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=10.0.0.100:11811
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener --ros-args --remap __node:=listener_discovery_server

Setup for container2:
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=10.0.0.100:11811
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args --remap __node:=talker_discovery_server

After deploying this setup, the server is running and if I have two ros2 containers with the listener and talker on the same machine as the discovery server, they work together. But communication with the container on the second machine is not possible
Is there a way to get them to commute? Any help would be appreciated.
